# How to get separate the previous % from an amount

Tags: math

I know it's pretty dumb question but I cannot figure it out. Although I'm quite weak in math, so don't be laugh XD.

So, Lets suppose I have `$2.25` amount and I added `15%` of this amount which is `$0.34`

```
$2.25 + 15%($0.34) =  $2.59
```

And now Let's just say I saved this final amount somewhere on notebook and come back after several months.

> So now I want `$0.34` separate from the final amount(`$2.59`).  How can
> I do that?

Comment: The 15% addition usually incurs  rounding, so `total = rounded(2.25*15/100, 0.01) + 2.25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is rly too trivial

```
x + x * 15 % = x + x * 0.15 = x * (1+0.15) = x * 1.15 = y
```

and in reverse

```
x = y / 1.15
```